# dotnet restore aborts without error

Tags: centos, asp.net-core, .net-core

On CentOS, `dotnet restore` aborts without an error:

```
dotnet --verbose restore

Telemetry is: Enabled
log  : Restoring packages for /home/forexsb/testapp/project.json...
Aborted
```

Here is my environment info:

```
dotnet --info

.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a2df9c2576

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  7
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.7-x64
```

This is my project.json content:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "buildOptions": {
     "debugType": "portable",
     "emitEntryPoint": true
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0"
   },
   "frameworks": {
     "netcoreapp1.1": {
       "dependencies": {
         "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
           "type": "platform",
           "version": "1.1.0"
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Mby try to upgrade your .NET Core to the latest version

Comment: I just installed it from the official Microsoft link: `curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=835019`